# Error: operator does not exist: character varying = integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I face a common problem. My Rails app works on my local machine, but after deploying to heroku it crashes:

```
<% unless @user.hotels.empty? %>
  <% @user.hotels.each do |hotel| %>
    <%= "#{hotel.description} #{hotel.name} in #{hotel.city}, #{hotel.country}" %><br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is from the heroku logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: SELECT "hotels".* FROM "hotels" WHERE ("hotels".user_id = 1)
                                                                ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "hotels".* FROM "hotels" WHERE ("hotels".user_id = 1)):
```

`@user.hotels.empty?` creates the error. I know, sqlite is pretty forgiving, but PostgreSQL is not. This is the foreign key in the hotel model: `user_id     :integer`

Heroku says:

```
Make sure the operator is adequate for the data type. ActiveRecord does this automatically when you use an interpolated condition form.

Array conditions:
:conditions => ['column1 = ? AND column2 = ?', value1, value2]

Hash conditions:
:conditions => { :column1 => value1, :column2 => value2 }
```

The migration looks like following:

```
class CreateHotels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :hotels do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :vanity_url
      t.integer :user_id
      ....
```

Comment: Just looking at the error message, it sure looks like Postgres considers hotels.user_id to be a varchar.

Comment: hm, but in the hotel model it is set as integer.

Comment: What is the data type of user_id **in the database**? The rails model is not important for this error message.

Comment: I added the part of the migration file. The datatype in the database is integer.

Comment: Please show us the table's definition **from the database** e.g as a CREATE TABLE statement

Comment: which version of PostgreSQL are you using

Comment: You can just change the column type

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795086/rails-3-1-heroku-pgerror-operator-does-not-exist-character-varying-integer

Answer (score 21):

This typically happens when the foreign key in the database is not an integer.

For example:

```
LINE 1: SELECT "hotels".* FROM "hotels" WHERE ("hotels".user_id = 1)
                                                                ^
```

In this case, PostgreSQL expects `user_id` to be an integer, but it almost looks like it's telling you that it was actually a varchar.

I would try removing the column and adding it again.