# Postgresql breaking rails querying functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a rails app that was working fine with sqlite but upon switching over to postgre I'm having an issue with this query:

```
User.find(1).ratings
```

Querying for just a works, e.g.

```
User.find(1)
```

produces

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

however if I append ratings like so:

```
User.find(1).ratings
```

produces

```
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rating Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = 1
PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...CT "ratings".* FROM "ratings"  WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = 1
                                                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "ratings".* FROM "ratings"  WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...CT "ratings".* FROM "ratings"  WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = 1
                                                                    ^
```

Whether a pass the :id as an int or string it still produces the above error.  The models are set up so :ratings belongs_to User which has_many :ratings.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Versions:  Rails 3.1.1, Ruby 1.9.2, devise 1.5.1

Comment: Is the `user_id` field/foreign key on the `ratings` table definitely an integer?

Comment: No, it's not I changed it and it worked thank you.  Why would that work on sqlite and not on postgre?

Comment: SQLite has a rather loose type system, PostgreSQL does not. You should be developing and deploying on the same stack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3.1. Heroku PGError: operator does not exist: character varying = integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795086/rails-3-1-heroku-pgerror-operator-does-not-exist-character-varying-integer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer

usually means that you're trying to compare two different data types for equality.  Some platforms will let you do that by silently coercing one to the other. SQLite will, and it will let you do a lot of things that are not compliant with SQL standards. PostgreSQL usually won't allow comparisons like this.  Since it prints

```
WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = 1
```

in the error message, it's telling you that, although you supplied an integer (`1`), the column ratings.user_id is actually a varchar().

---

SQLite isn't SQL.  Here I use the universal data type "wibble".

```
sqlite> create table test (n integer not null, s wibble not null);
sqlite> insert into test values (1, 'Wibble');
sqlite> insert into test values ('Wibble', 1);
sqlite> select * from test;
1|Wibble
Wibble|1
```

SQLite is happy to let me insert "Wibble" into an integer column.  That should at least give you pause, if not nightmares.

PostgreSQL is free and available for many platforms. If you're anticipating deployment on Heroku, I can't see any reason not to install PostgreSQL and develop against it instead of using SQLite.

Comment: Rails defaults to SQLite (unfortunately) because it is supposed to be "easy" to use. Shame that the Rails people don't have any respect for databases.