# Rails3 has_many through working on local but fail on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm using sqlit3 for local and Postgre for heroku.

Everything works fine until i upload my files to heroku. Here is my model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :unit

  has_friends
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :unit, :floor
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :block
end

class Block < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :block, :units_attributes
  has_many :units, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :units, allow_destroy: true
  belongs_to :postalcode
end

class Postalcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :postalcode, :blocks_attributes
  has_many :blocks, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blocks, allow_destroy: true
  belongs_to :neighbourhood
end

class Neighbourhood < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :streetname, :postalcodes_attributes
  has_many :postalcodes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :blocks, :through => :postalcodes
  has_many :units, :through => :blocks
  has_many :users, :through => :units
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :postalcodes, allow_destroy: true
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :streetname, :presence => true
end
```

i troubleshooted and found that the problem is with this method in the controller.

```
@neighbours = current_user.unit.block.postalcode.neighbourhood.users
```

Although @neighbours = current_user.unit.block.postalcode.neighbourhood works perfectly fine.

Please help, i'm desperate, i have tried googling for it one whole day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this answer to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8795572/429758)

It is quite likely the error is coming up from `WHERE "postalcodes"."neighbourhood_id" = 1` which indicates that `neighbourhood_id` in postalcodes table is created as a String, instead of an integer.

Follow the steps mentioned in the answer accordingly, and change it to an Integer.

Comment: almost right, but yeah. it's my user model unit_id, werid. but thanks, i love u :D